# Accept URLs as parameter and returns for ImageView in Java

Tags: java, android, bitmap, imageview

I'm trying to get this resolve for days but no luck yet. Please help me kindly. 
I need to write a function to accepts URLs as parameter and returns for ImageView. 
Could someone kindly show me how to modify this code to do that? it gives me red line under `imgURL.setImageBitmap(directory.getString(TAG_IMAGE));`

```
public class ViewProfileActivity extends Activity {

    ImageView imgURL;
    TextView txtName;

    String eid; 

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

    private static final String url_veiw_directory = "http://website.com/app/include/view_directory.php";

    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_DIRECTORY = "directory";
    private static final String TAG_ID = "eid";
    private static final String TAG_IMAGE = "image";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";  

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.view_directory);

        Intent i = getIntent();

        eid = i.getStringExtra(TAG_ID);     


        new GetDirectoryDetails().execute();

    }   

    class GetDirectoryDetails extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {

                    int success;
                    try {

                        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", eid));

                        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_veiw_directory, "GET", params);

                        Log.d("Single Directory Details", json.toString());

                        success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                        if (success == 1) {                     

                            JSONArray directoryObj = json.getJSONArray(TAG_DIRECTORY);  
                            JSONObject directory = directoryObj.getJSONObject(0);

                            imgURL = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
                            txtName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);                       


                            imgURL.setImageBitmap(directory.getString(TAG_IMAGE));
                            txtName.setText(directory.getString(TAG_NAME));                         


                        }else{

                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });

            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What does the 'red line' say in the IDE you are using?

Comment: you are setting a string to a ImageView? Why would you assume this would work?

Comment: if i hover over it, it gives me 1 quick fix change to setImageURI. but it doesn't make any difference if i change to it.

Comment: You should use an image loading library to do this. There are many available

Comment: sorry, I'm new to android and java..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I see the problem. `ImageView.setImageBitmap` needs a `Bitmap` object as argument. A `String` won't do.
You should try to load the `JSONObject` as a `Bitmap` object.

This could be the answer you are looking for:
[Loading a Bitmap from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2472175/1110688)

Comment: That's OK. Please look at the following [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2472175/1110688)

Answer (score 3):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageBitmap%28android.graphics.Bitmap%29

There is no `setImageBitmap()`-method in ImageView, that accepts a string as a parameter. You have to supply a Bitmap.

Instead, you could use the [BitmapFactory](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics) to create your bitmap, like this:

`setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(directory.getString(TAG_IMAGE)));`

**EDIT**: Sorry, forgot that it was a URL you wanted to decode. See @MarchingHome answer for this.

Comment: could you give me some sample kindly?

Comment: `setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(directory.getString(TAG_IMAGE)));`
Look here for more info about BitmapFactory:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html